# Proper way to type events in callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events

Two days ago I started digging Angular cause I might have to use it in the future.

I'm currently studying components communication, from child to parent, and I found several ways of doing it, in every following example, the ChildComponent has this property:

```js
@Output changeSignal : EventEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

**First way**

```html
<input [(ngModel)]='message' (keyup)='handleKeyUp' />
```

```js
message : string : '';

handleKeyUp() : void {
    this.changeSignal.emit(this.message);
}
```

This solution makes us use a property, which only use is to be transmitted to the parent, I don't like the idea of remembering useless data.

**Second way**

```html
<input (keyup)='handleKeyUp($event)' />
```

```js
handleKeyUp(event : any) : void {
    this.changeSignal.emit(event.target.value);
    // console.log(event.constructor.name);
}
```

We can also not specify the type of the event, I don't consider this as a good practice in typescript.

**Third way**

The console.log() from the previous example says KeyboardEvent and event.target is of type EventTarget, butt that class doesn't seem to define the 'value' property.

```js
handleKeyUp(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
    // Error in the terminal
    this.changeSignal.emit(event.target.value);
}
```

The 'value' property is specific to some HTMLElement, like HTMLInputElement, in order to prevent the error, we have to cast it:

```js
handleKeyUp(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
    this.changeSignal.emit((<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value);
}
```

This doesn't feel fine.

**Fourth way**

```html
<input (keyup)='handleKeyUp($event.target.value) />
```

```js
HandleKeyUp(inputContent : string) : void {
    this.changeSignal.emit(inputContent);
}
```

We let the input tag handle it's specificity, but the html template is harder to read and contains behavior, which should be in the javascript file.

Which one of the four ways would you consider as the best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you feel about

```
<input #nameInput (keyup)="handleKeyUp(nameInput.value)"/>
```

in angular it is considered as a good practice to leave light DOM and events handling in the template (and sometimes in directives) so your ts would be able to contain only model related logic.
Also you could create a directive that emmits bound `<input>` value to the output event if you don't like the way I proposed

Comment: You, sir, just made my night.
I was going for a sleepless night thinking about it.
I'm glad the framework provides solution to what I consider to be a "javascript flaw".
Thank you very much!

Comment: My conclusion: 
1) don't use $event
2) use #reference instead
3) don't send event to the callback, extract the data and send it to the callback
4) If you need to remember the value, ngModel is the best pick
5) if you just want to emit the value, #reference.value is the best pick